# Add counter to textarea input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script which serves the purpose but would like to add a counter to visually inform the user of remaining characters.

script

```
function limit(element, max_chars)
{
    if(element.value.length > max_chars)
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
}
```

html

```
<textarea onkeyup="javascript:limit(this, 150)" onblur="limit(this,150)" name="message" rows="4" style="width:99%; margin: 0;" class="unfocusinput"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a couple of lines to your limit function that get some element and update its content based on the value of element.value.length.

html:

```
<textarea ...></textarea>
<span id="contentLen">count goes here</span>
```

javascript:

```
function limit(element, max_chars)
{
    if(element.value.length > max_chars)
    {
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    }
    document.getElementById ('contentLen').innerHTML = element.value.length;
}
```

Comment: it counts the number of chars typed and not chars remaining. how do i do this?

Comment: Well in that case you'd just do a simple subtraction of element.value.length from max_chars.

Answer (score 1):

Friend;

You can use this function on onKeyDown

```
if(document.getElementById(element).value.length==limit && event.keyCode!=8)
document.getElementById(element).blur();
```

PS : keycode 8 is backspace.

Comment: What about delete or return? :)

Answer (score 0):

script

```
function limit(element, max_chars, counter)
{
    if(element.value.length > max_chars)
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    document.getElementById(counter).innerHTML = element.value.length - max_chars; 
}
```

html

```
<textarea onkeyup="javascript:limit(this,150,'someCounter')" onblur="limit(this,150,'someCounter')" name="message" rows="4" style="width:99%; margin: 0;" class="unfocusinput"></textarea>
<span id"someCounter">150</span> chars left
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [jQuery plugin](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/limit/) that does just that.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out. btw the amount of plugins one is loading-up these days is gradually getting out-of hand.

Comment: ...No. Writing your own code or copying and pasting is out of hand. Using libraries has and always will be the better way to solve problems.

Comment: Providing a link is not a solution and using a plugin is not always the better way.

Comment: @Hussein: Yes, yes it is. You tend to be wrong a lot, I see. ;)

Comment: The overall quality of available jQuery plug-ins is immensely variable and generally pretty low. I'd say @Hussein has a point, although the downvote is unwarranted.